# How to use jQuery ajax in Silex Insert post

Tags: php, jquery, silex

I'm trying to do some insert into the database then view the post list and 
display it by ajax, but i'm not pretty sure how to do it.

Here's my route:

```
$app->match('/status', 'Post\StatusPost\Controller\StatusPostController::statusAction')->bind('main');
```

Then on my controller I process the insert stuffs then access the Model entity
and pass it into the view

```
$posts = new Post();
$posts = $posts->allPosts($app);

return $app['twig']->render('status.html.twig', [
  'form' => $form->createView(),
  'posts' => $app->json($posts),
]);
```

Then on my view there's just a simple text area.
So upon submitting the post it should display it via ajax

Here's my js script

```
$('#status-btn').click(function(){
$.getJSON('/status', function(data){
  console.log(data);
  var html;
  $.each(data, function(entryIndex, entry){
    html += '<div class="status-container">';
    html += '<h3 class="status-title">' + entry.name + '</h3>';
    html += '<img src="' + window.location.href + '/images/' + entry.image + '">';
    html += '<p class="status-content">' + entry.status + '</p>';
    html += '<span class="status-time">' + entry.timestamp + '</p>';
    html += '</div>';
  });
  $('.content-container').html(html);
});
```

});

But upon submitting it nothing happens.

Comment: where is `status-btn` from?is it dynamically added?

Comment: Oh sorry thats on the view template

Comment: `<form action="" method="post">
            {{ form_widget(form) }}
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="status-btn"/>
          </form>`

Comment: add `event.preventDefault()` on your click event or change the type of button `button`

Comment: what action did you do ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you say GetJSON, but you send Html? cannot work. you should send a JsonResponse or you must set the Headers properly 'Content-Type: application/json'. If you use GetJSON the browser tries automatically convert the response from the php script (no matter if its silex) and the header must be of type JSON.